# Kubernetes Ingress starts up with Fake Certificate and does not pick the intended certificate

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress

I am facing an issue running application via a set of prepackaged Helm Charts. This chart creates an ingress with a secret. While I can see the ingress and the secret getting successfully, and the Ingress correctly referencing the secret as well, the ingress always returns a fake certificate, when I invoke it with the command.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername connectivity-proxy.cs-dev.transparent-proxy.eurekacloud.io -connect connectivity-proxy.cs-dev.transparent-proxy.eurekacloud.io:443
CONNECTED(00000004)
depth=0 O = Acme Co, CN = Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 O = Acme Co, CN = Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
verify return:1
```

Unfortunately I do not have options to use args like --default-ssl-certificate as it is a prepackaged helm chart and moreover there are other ingresses with different certificates.

Is there anything else I can explore?

Snippet of the deployed ingress. The secret mentioned in the tls.secretName is correct and as expected.

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: connectivity-proxy.cs-dev.transparent-proxy.eurekacloud.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: connectivity-proxy-tunnel-0
            port:
              number: 8042
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - connectivity-proxy.cs-dev.transparent-proxy.eurekacloud.io
    secretName: pr-ingress-secret
```

Snippet of the secret pr-ingress-secret. The base 64 encoded values are correct as expected.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: <Base 64 encoded value of CA Cert>
  tls.crt: <Base 64 encoded value of TLS Cert>
  tls.key: <Base 64 encoded value of TLS Key>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: connectivity-proxy
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: connectivity-proxy
  creationTimestamp: "2024-03-02T07:32:56Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: pr-ingress-secret
  namespace: connectivity-proxy
  resourceVersion: "3674684903"
  uid: 401e2621-789b-4ecd-803c-8e3ceb56513b
type: Opaque
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get after you install an ingress controller is the ability to  interpret the manifest of `kind: Ingress`

You need to create an Ingress definition and apply it to your cluster.
Within the ingress definition you can specify the certificate to be used - you basically point to a secret which holds the TLS private key and certificate. The secret should be of the type `kubernetes.io/tls` not `Opaque`

```
kubectl create secret tls my-tls-secret --key /path/to/tls.key --cert /path/to/tls.crt -n your-namespace
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ssl-ingress
  namespace: your-namespace
  annotations:
    # Use nginx as the ingress controller
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # Enable SSL redirect to automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: my-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

The annotations are ingress controller specific. Depending on the ingress controller and your needs, they may need to be changed or removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt revert. The Kind: Ingress is present, and I excluded it for brevity. Here is the actual ingress that I have

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "10"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "120"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "120"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    
.......
```
Ideally this should be picked up by the Ingress Controller I feel. Isn;t it?

Comment: Do you  have the specified Ingress Class present in your cluster? What's the output of `kubectl get ingressclass`? Is the secret present in the same namespace?

Comment: Thanks for the note. 
```
kubectl get ingressclass -n-connectivity-proxy
NAME    CONTROLLER             PARAMETERS   AGE
nginx   k8s.io/ingress-nginx   <none>       586d
```
Also the secret and the ingress are in the same namespace

Comment: The secret should be of the type `kubernetes.io/tls` not `Opaque`

Answer (score 0):

Its likely you haven't installed cert-manager https://cert-manager.io/ in your cluster and/or configured it correctly to request the certificate from LetsEncrypt (this is assuming you're not intending to upload your own certificate that has been issued via another CA -- Symantec, Entrust, Verisign, digiCert, etc).

Having an ingress controller installed will allow the certificate to be served on requests (by default, this is the fake certificate you are seeing), but not having cert-manager installed will mean that cert never changes and you will forever get that fake cert.